# Does onGestureEvent of TapGestureHandler never fire?

Tags: react-native-gesture-handler

Here is a Snack of the issue below - https://snack.expo.io/@noitidart/tapgesturehandler-ongestureevent

Does `onGestureEvent` for `TapGestureHandler` never trigger? The docs do not make this clear. This seems to be happening to me:

```
import Reanimated from 'react-native-reanimated';

const handleStateChange = () => console.log('state changed');
const handleGestureEvent = () => console.log('got gesture event');

<TapGestureHandler
  onHandlerStateChange={handleStateChange}
  onGestureEvent={handleGestureEvent}>
  <Reanimated.View
    style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
  />
</TapGestureHandler>
```

You will see on tap it never triggers ('gesture event')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this as well, the docs in gesture handler on discrete vs continuous gestures mentions it:

```
Keep in mind that onGestureEvent is only generated in continuous gesture handlers and shouldn't be used in the TapGestureHandler and other discrete handlers.
```

source: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/about-handlers

This is very confusing since examples using TapGestureHandler in Reanimated appear to use onGestureEvent, but I have found that handling the state change myself is the way to go.
Good news is, it is incredibly simple to manage since it is a discrete gesture.

Comment: This is awesome thank you for this share! Exactly, the TapGestureHandler examples using onGestureEvent made it super confusing.